# Is there a way to display a form for just some specific time

Tags: c#, winforms

Can we show the windows form for just some specific time span, say 1 minute, then close it automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a Timer control from Toolbox.
Set some attributes.

```
    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
    this.timer1.Interval = 60000;
    this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
```

and define Tick event handler

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), let it close the form after the amount of time you need it to.

Comment: Check the accepted solution - that's the useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer, and when the timer fires, call this.Close().

Comment: Check the accepted solution - that's the useful answer.